# How can I make QStandardItems in a QTreeView work like buttons opening a new window (submenu)?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview, qpushbutton, qstandarditem

I am fairly new to PyQt5 or rather to Qt in general, so sorry if this question is really dumb or basic.

I am assigned working on an application for some rather complex scientific data analysis that uses PyQt5. Now my current task is to create an interface to enter all kinds of parameters in a treelike structure. I use a class  TreeView(QWidget) for this purpose, loosely following this guide: http://pharma-sas.com/common-manipulation-of-qtreeview-using-pyqt5/

Now my boss wants that for some of the items in the tree it should be possible to click them just like a QPushButton to open a submenu, in which one can enter some more parameters (could be a QTableView I guess). As far as I know it is not possible to append QPushButtons just like QStandardItems right?

So what would be the best way to do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Please be more careful with terminology: with "submenu" do you mean a context menu, or a new dialog/window?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @musicamante I mean a new window

Comment: Use the [`clicked()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#clicked) signal or [`setIndexWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget).